# First build of clojurescript with external library reports error (but works)

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I have the following project structure:

```
next
 +- project.clj
 +- resources
     +- node_run.js
 +- src
     +- next
         +- core.cljc
```

**project.clj**

```
(defproject next "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.48"]
                 [org.clojure/test.check "0.8.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.0"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds
           {:node-dev
             {:source-paths ["src"]
              :compiler {:target :nodejs
                         :output-to "node_dev_main.js"
                         :output-dir "out"
                         :cache-analysis true
                         :source-map true
                         :optimizations :none}}}})
```

**src/next/core.cljc**

```
(ns next.core
  #?(:cljs (:require
         [cljs.nodejs :as nodejs]
         [clojure.test.check :as tc]
         [clojure.test.check.generators :as gen]
         [clojure.test.check.properties :as prop :include-macros true])))

  #?(:cljs (nodejs/enable-util-print!))

  #?(:cljs (set! *main-cli-fn* -main))

  (defn -main [& args] (println (gen/sample (gen/vector gen/int))))
```

**resources/node_run.js**

```
require('../out/goog/bootstrap/nodejs')
require('../node_dev_main.js')
require('../out/next/core')
next.core._main()
```

When I run for the first time

```
lein cljsbuild once
```

the compiler errors with "no such namespace gen".

Despite this, executing

```
node resources/node_run.js
```

works as expected. On subsequent builds, there are no compile errors.

I do not want bogus errors to appear any time a new dependency is introduced. Is there a way of reconfiguring the project so that no errors are produced during the initial build?